# Pivot getting multiple records

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on pivot functionality.
I'm having 2 tables one is userinfo and another is hobbies.
My table will be as like below image.
[image: Table Image]
I'm saving the hobbies with comma separated data in userinfo.
I want all the comma separated hobbies with their respective column names.
I tried, but getting indivdual records for each hobbies instead of the single row
as like below image.
[image: Output currently]
My code is as follows :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--drop table Temptbl1
--drop table Temptbl2
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Temptbl1)
drop table Temptbl1
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Temptbl2)
drop table Temptbl2
SELECT * INTO Temptbl1 FROM UserInfo CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitData(Hobbies,',')
--select * from Temptbl1
Select * into Temptbl2 from Temptbl1 s,Hobbies h where s.DividedItem=h.Hid
--select * from Temptbl2
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(HName) from Hobbies 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
    print @cols
set @query = 'SELECT distinct UId,UName,UAge,Hid, '+@cols +'  from ( select 
* from Temptbl2 )
          x
          pivot 
         (max(DividedItem) for HName in (' + @cols + ') ) p '
select * from Temptbl2
exec(@query)
```

Comment: It is very hard to read your screen captures.  Please include all information directly in the question as _text_.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, you can find the code in code snippet. I'm getting multiple individual records for each hobby result.

Comment: If you observe for Uid 1 I got 2 records one for singing and another for dancing.
I want both to be in single record.

Comment: There is no good reason for images of your data. Would you enjoy the transcription effort from an image of a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting all columns from the `temptbl2` and you do not need them. The `Hid`  column is selected there and it is making the rows unique and the pivot `fails` to aggregate the results correctly. Just change it to this:

```
set @query = 'SELECT distinct UId,UName,UAge, '+@cols +'  from ( select  UId,UName,UAge, DividedItem, HName 
 from Temptbl2 )
          x
          pivot 
         (max(DividedItem) for HName in (' + @cols + ') ) p '
```

And you will be OK.

---

Here is full working example on `SQL Server 2016 SP1`. I am using `string_split` to split the data and temporary table to store it. Also, change a little bit the join syntax (your is obsolete and should not be used). You can adapt the code below to work on your environment easily:

```
DECLARE @hobbies TABLE
(
    [HiD] INT
   ,[HName] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @hobbies ([HiD], [HName])
VALUES (1, 'Reading')
      ,(2, 'Singing')
      ,(3, 'Dancing');

DECLARE @UserInfo TABLE
(
    [UID] INT
   ,[UName] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[UAddress] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[UAge] TINYINT
   ,[Hobbies] VARCHAR(12)
)

INSERT INTO @UserInfo ([UID], [UName], [UAddress], [UAge], [Hobbies])
VALUES (1, 'Abc', 'addr1', 25, '2,3')
      ,(2, 'Def', 'addr2', 27, '1,2,3')
      ,(3, 'Ghi', 'addr3', 20, '1');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST;

SELECT *
INTO #TEST
FROM @UserInfo UI
CROSS APPLY string_split(UI.[Hobbies], ',') HS
INNER JOIN @hobbies H
    ON HS.[value] = h.[HiD]

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

Select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(HName) from @hobbies 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT distinct UId,UName,UAge, '+@cols +'  from ( select  uid, uname, uage, hname, value
 from #TEST )
          x
          pivot 
         (max(value) for HName in (' + @cols + ') ) p '

exec(@query)
```

[image]